# Is wget distributed with all UNIX platforms as default

Tags: php, unix, wget

I'm building a PHP script (only for Unix).  My script needs to download http files in background so I want to use `wget` for this purpose.

But I have a doubt. Is `wget` distributed with all UNIX platforms as default or not?

Comment: It's not in OS X Snow Leopard, I don't know about newer versions of OS X. It only has `curl`.

Comment: Err, UNIX is a _very_ encompassing term, _not_ just Linux and BSD derivatives but a massive full suite (AIX, HPUX, Solaris, QNX, and many others you've probably never heard of).

Comment: Why do you script in PHP ? PHP is relevant for web servers, but it is not the best or more common scripting language. You could code a Posix shell script, or use Python or Perl etc...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Hi, I'm writing script for my web application.

Comment: Then, use PHP CURL. I am not sure to understand what you mean by downloading in the background. You might use Ajax techniques (+ PHP CURL) in your application to download by small pieces and give feedback about downloading in the client browser.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch When I'm downloading file with `PHP CURL`. Script waiting for downloading file. After download file. Remaing PHP script runiing. But I need to download in async mode and run remaing PHP code without waiting for download.

Comment: So you need the CURL MULTI interface.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `CURL MULTI interface` ? I don't know about it. Thanks for great suggestion. Now I'm googleing about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Unix systems (but probably not all, perhaps some low-end embedded Linuxes might not have them, but they might not have PHP neither) have either [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

However, you should avoid forking processes to download. Why can't you use [PHP CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) (that is, the glue code in PHP for [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/))? This would avoid depending on external shells and binaries, and should be slightly faster (since it does not need to [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) any process).

CURL is flexible enough to permit downloading by small chunks, etc. Use [PHP curl_multi_init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) etc etc... Read about [libcurl multi](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) interface.

Comment: Hi, I know about PHP curl. But It's not possible to download files in background.

Comment: Why is it not possible? You could fork your PHP process. However, I believe that you might be wrong in coding a non-web related script in PHP...

Answer (score 2):

No.  It isn't on Mac OS X 10.9.4 (Mavericks) by default.